# Android Studio Google Maps API

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps

So I am making an application for android mobile devices, using Android Studio. The application involves use of the Google Maps API, but I am encountering issues whenever the Google Maps Activity is not my launcher activity. Here is the manifest.xml code for which it works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.drexelnavigationapplication_20">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".dna_map"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_dna_map">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".dna_registration">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here is the manifest code where I attempt to make a different activity with a button to switch to Maps activity the launcher, and the application crashes upon pressing the button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.drexelnavigationapplication_20">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".dna_map"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_dna_map">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".dna_registration">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the code for the Intent function on the button(using the onClick property) that completes the screen switch:

```
package com.example.drexelnavigationapplication_20;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class dna_registration extends AppCompatActivity {

//INTENT FUNCTION IN QUESTION, 
    private void switchScreens_Maps(View view){ 
        Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), dna_map.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dna_registration);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong, that causes the application to crash upon switching screens?

Comment: how was your question Android Studio related?

Comment: Please add the exception stack

Comment: @Prakhar - Can you please grab logcat and paste in your question that shows error ?

Comment: The click function needs to be public: `public void switchScreens_Maps(View view)`    Also, take out the duplicated `android.intent.action.MAIN` action.  Remove the intent filter section completely from the map activity.

Answer (score 0):

Your API key may be wrong in string value